# if three hermitian operators commute in pairs, are they all mutually diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A,B,C$ be hermitian operators, such that $[A,B]=[B,C]=[A,C]=0$.
>   
> Does that mean we can find a set of mutual eigenstates?

I believe the answer is "Yes", since this was assumed during some derivation I'm reading through. If there's no degeneracy for one of the operators, it's quite straightforward. Otherwise, I'm not sure how to prove this, or whether it has anything to do with the hermiticity of the operators.

Comment: Are you in a finite-dimensional complex vector space, for example? Or possibly an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space? If the latter, there can easily be situations where a (bounded/continuous) hermitian operator has no eigenvectors/eigenstates in the Hilbert space itself. Apart from that, the answer is "yes", that commuting self-adjoint operators have "as many simultaneous eigenvectors as possible" (with the latter needing a little qualification, depending on your situation...) Clarify?

Comment: That's right, it actually comes from a derivation in quantum mechanics for the hydrogen atom. Could you please refer me to some further explanation? I tried looking up for this, seems like I'm missing the relevant term to lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in a finite-dimensional complex vector space $V$, with any number of commuting self-adjoint operators $S,T,\ldots$, there is a basis consisting of simultaneous eigenvectors. The key point is that $T$ stabilizes the $S$-eigenspaces: for $v$ in the $\lambda$-eigenspace $V_\lambda$ of $S$, 
$$
S(Tv) \;=\; (ST)(v) \;=\; (TS)(v) \;=\; T(Sv) \;=\; T(\lambda\cdot v)
\;=\; \lambda\cdot Tv
$$
Thus, from the $S$-decomposition $V=\bigoplus_\lambda V_\lambda$, $T$ stabilizes each $V_\lambda$, and is still hermitian there, so decomposes each $V_\lambda$ into eigenspaces. Each of these "nested" eigenspaces consists of simultaneous eigenspaces for both $S,T$. A "downward induction" proves the analogous result for any finite number of operators. An extra trick, using the finite-dimensionality, gives the same result for an arbitrary set of commuting operators on a finite-dimensional space.

In the infinite-dimensional situation, if all the commuting self-adjoint operators are *compact*, then a similar discussion succeeds.

Even without compactness, it is still true (by the same computation) that commuting operators preserve each others' eigenspaces (if any).